# how to make an input type'button' act like type='submit'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input type radio:

```
<input type="radio"  name="status">Semi-Finalist
<input type="radio" id="finalist" name="status">Finalist
<input type="radio"  name="status">Reject
<input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Submit">
```

When the user select **Finalist** the Modal (pop up window) show appear and ask additional questions, but If **Semi-finalist** or **Reject** is checked, submit the form when the "Submit" button is clicked.  This is why I can't use `type="submit"`

Thank you...

**UPDATE:**
here is the js that show the modal

```
//finalist Modal
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".submitButton").click(function(){

    if($('#finalist').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#myModalFinalist").modal('show');
    }

  });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `type="submit"`.

When writing the JavaScript event handler to decide if you need to show additional questions or not, conditionally call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submission.

```js
$("form [type='submit']").on('click', show_additional);

function show_additional(event) {
  if ($("[value=finalist]:checked").length) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Also show additional fields now");
  } else {
    alert("Just submit normally");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="semi">Semi-Finalist</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="finalist">Finalist</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="reject">Reject</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

NB: The form won't actually submit in this demo because of Stackoverflow's sandboxing.

Comment: well said. One little quirk I hate and always have to look up is whether `event.preventDefault()` is enough or you also need `return false;`

Comment: preventDefault is enough. return false is just a hangover from the 90s when we used onclick *attributes*

Comment: hangover, ha! Actually that makes sense. Thanks for the input

Comment: Thank you! it works on Chrome, but not in Firefox 40.0.3 =(

Comment: Got it! I passed the event variable to my .submitButton

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used: Thanks to @Quentin I could figure it out!

```
<input type="radio"  name="status">Semi-Finalist
<input type="radio" id="finalist" name="status">Finalist
<input type="radio"  name="status">Reject
<input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Submit">


$(document).ready(function(){


$(".submitButton").click(function(event){

    if($('#finalist').is(':checked')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#myModalFinalist").modal('show');
    }

  });
});
```